# Android: Saving Bitmap to phone storage

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm having a problem saving a bitmap to the phone storage.  It seems as if I can't create a new file.  I get the exception--> *java.io.Exception: open failed: EAccess (Permission denied) at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:940)*.

The strFileName that is being used is */storage/sdcard0/SpenSDK/images/testimage_00*

The weird thing is that this code was working in a previous project.  I am wondering if anyone has and idea as to why this exception is being thrown.

Here is the code to save to the phone storage as a PNG.

```
private boolean saveBitmapPNG(String strFileName, Bitmap bitmap){
        if(strFileName==null || bitmap==null){
             System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - NAME OR BITMAP");
             return false;
        }

        boolean bSuccess1 = false;  
        boolean bSuccess2;
        boolean bSuccess3;
        File saveFile = new File(strFileName);          

        if(saveFile.exists()) {
            if(!saveFile.delete())
                System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - could not delete existing");
                return false;
        }

        try {
            bSuccess1 = saveFile.createNewFile();//----------------->EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
        } catch (IOException e1) {
             System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - could not create new file"); 
             e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
            bSuccess2 = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); //----------------->EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
            System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - could not compress");//-->3

            bSuccess2 = false;
        }
        try {
            if(out!=null) //----------------->OUT == null here
            {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                bSuccess3 = true;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - could not close");//-->4
                bSuccess3 = false;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("!!!error saving image - false in SavePNG - could not close (exception");
            bSuccess3 = false;
        }finally
        {
            if(out != null)
            {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }           
        }   
        return (bSuccess1 && bSuccess2 && bSuccess3);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this permission in manifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Check the link for more information

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I can't believe I forgot to update the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Also you can get rid of createNewFile. If the file does not exists will be created

Comment: why should he get rid of createNewFile. Asking for my clarification. bcoz of this "The strFileName that is being used is */storage/sdcard0/SpenSDK/images/testimage_00"?

Comment: agreed @blackbelt but he has this return (bSuccess1 && bSuccess2 && bSuccess3);

Comment: he can always returns bSuccess2 && bSuccess3;

Answer (score 1):

In addition to permission, given in previous answers, you should get path to sdcard by using method

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

and append needed directory to returned path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Does your hardcoded path really point to the sd card?